# Attempting to append the path of a css/js file with a date stamp

Tags: javascript, css, gulp

I am using Gulp and I want to append the file name with a dateStamp. I want to do this so I can invalidate the file using cloud front.

Is there a built in function in Gulp that allows me to grab the time a file was modified at last?

I'm new to Gulp and all its crazy intricacies, so please be gentle...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `stat` function of fs module :

```
var fs = require('fs');

fs.stat(path, [callback])
```

Where `mtime` is the time when file data last modified.

[Documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_stat_time_values)